# Language Choice for Web interface on embedded device

Tags: embedded-linux

I need to find a good language to program a web interface for an embedded device (Linux).

Of the traditional web languages I only know PHP and to be honest I am hesitant to use it because of it's mushy typing system. I'm no professional PHP developer - I have only used it in my spare time - so my judgment may be way off. I just always disliked not having clear parameter and return types (and the IDE suggestions that goes along with it).

Are there any alternatives with stronger type system (I don't mind the dynamic part) that would be suitable for such an application?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the complexity of the web interface and the hardware resources you have.

Because, especially if

- you have tight hardware constraints;
- the web interface does not have to perform very complex things but
  only managing the configuration of the device or someting like that;
- the device in meant to be installed in a private (or at least not
  public) network;

then you can even use a shell as interpreter and perform the sanity checks of the input by using javascript at client side (you can do this **ONLY** if the installation environment is not hostile).

If this is not your scenario, I would move the sanity checks in the pages of the interpreter to reduce the possibility that a malicious HTTP request can exploit your program. Spending time in sanitizing the user input is much more important than having to deal with strong typization. Otherwise everybody would write cgi in C/C++ with libcgi or with any other library. Try to search in google for "c cgi library" or "c++ cgi library", you'll find a lot of them, but they are rarely used.