# web interface for C++ app on embedded Linux device

Tags: web-services, embedded

I'd like to implement a communication link between an Apache-hosted webpage and my custom C++ app running on a small Linux device such as a [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/) or a [DD-Wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com).

There's a tutorial [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Web-Control-of-Raspberry-Pi-GPIO/) for the Raspberry Pi that uses buttons on a webpage to control LEDs on GPIO pins. The example uses MySQL as a communication interface between the webpage and a script and the script has read/write access to GPIO. Although MySQL offers the advantage of mature/ubiquitous interfaces to Apache hosted webpages and to C++, it might slower and have a larger flash & RAM footprint than necessary.

In an attempt to find a communications link that is smaller/faster than MySQL, I have an example that uses Javascript that does XML-RPC to a C++ app. But, [this post](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?257212-queation-about-XMLRPC-in-Javascript) way back in 02-24-2012, implies that xmlrpc is obsolete and could be replaced by something more modern (JSON, REST) but the posts lacks details about these methodologies.

Another option considered is something like [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) or other embedded libraries, but it will have a learning curve and web developers aren't likely to be familiar with it.

My question is: what would be a good architecture to implement a web interface for a custom C++ app on a resource-constrained device like a Raspberry Pi or other embedded Linux device?

Assumptions:

- Apache is prefered because it fits in memory and web developers are familiar with it.
- Interface should be 'modern'
- pages are simple text-only, about 10 pages, 90% of the data fields
  are read-only and the other 10% are editable fields.
- The webserver is on a private network with no more than 3 users. The qty of users is
  enforced using security/login.
- Embedded ARM platform that boots from SD
- CGI (launching a process for each transaction) is assumed to be slower
  than necessary. FastCGI might be OK.

Similar questions found that didn't answer my question:
 - [Language Choice for Web interface on embedded device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521926/language-choice-for-web-interface-on-embedded-device)
 - [Designing Web Interface for Embedded System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984709/designing-web-interface-for-embedded-system)

Comment: Have you looked at WSDL? It is the more modern day xmlrpc.

Comment: Is there any particular problem with XML-RPC other than "it's obsolete"? I've used XML-RPC on smaller devices with great success.

Comment: Also, "CGI is too slow" implies a reasonably high performance target. Can you give us any more information on what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Oh god. Apache? Why would you want such an overkill monster on an embedded device? I would suggest using a smaller server and instead of using cgi use a rest api handler. A very lightweight setup is to use uhttpd with ubus plugin and then to write your system code in C and just expose it's functionality through json api on ubus. You can then completely separate your web interface from your system code and you can minimize strain on the embedded server by only serving static html which you turn into a dynamic application with javascript and ajax.

No interpreter, no cgi, just ajax and ubus backend.

Answer (score 0):

I do that and more on my rPI using Nodejs with the express, Socket.io, Mongojs modules